# How to retain page selection on browser back using backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, browser

In my backbone JS web application, there are two pages i.e. page1 and page2. Page1 has different form controls like radio buttons, check-boxes and drop-downs. I select some controls and navigate to page2. But when I click on browser back button to go to previous page page1 I am loosing all the values in page1. My question is how can I retain the values or information without loosing it. I am looking for backbone JS specific solution.

Comment: have you tried using cookie?

Comment: Are you not working on a single page application..?

Comment: It's not an SPA. Page navigation is standard URL redirection.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the data in localstorage or a full fledged database.Define this in your collection, and use the fetch/save methods accordingly.

```
localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("page1"),
```

There are plenty of detailed examples on the implementation for localstorage.Here's [a link](http://www.mattzeunert.com/2013/01/26/minimal-backbone-localstorage-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

Presuming page1 and page2 are routed views and not page loads then when you go back to page1 the render method fires and knows nothing of your previous input values so to capture them you could update the model in page1 with form values as and when they are entered e.g. on change and then render the form with this model instead of a clean or new model. The model should remain in memory when routing to page2 and back to page1.